# Errors resulting from upgrading my CXF version from 2.7.7 to 3.1.8

Tags: apache, cxf, javax.ws.rs

pom.xml

```
<cxf.core>3.1.8</cxf.core>
    <cxf.version>3.1.8</cxf.version>
 <jsr311.api.version>1.1.1</jsr311.api.version>   <javax.ws.rs.api.version>2.0.1</javax.ws.rs.api.version>    

 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.ws.rs.api.version}</version>
      </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsr311.api.version}</version>
      </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.core}</version>
      </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
```

Exception is :

```
WARN:2017-07-27 17:19:37.903:localhost-startStop-1:"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt":org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'caServiceClient' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/vn0kt7d/Documents/workspace-checkout1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/checkoutservice/WEB-INF/lib/checkout-adapter-1.0.0.75-SNAPSHOT.jar!/environmentConfig/default/customer-account-client.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactoryBean:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'caServiceClient' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/vn0kt7d/Documents/workspace-checkout1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/checkoutservice/WEB-INF/lib/checkout-adapter-1.0.0.75-SNAPSHOT.jar!/environmentConfig/default/customer-account-client.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at com.walmart.platform.scm.client.execution.ScmServletContextListener.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ScmServletContextListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactoryBean
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.AbstractJAXRSClient.getJAXRSBean(AbstractJAXRSClient.java:360)
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.AbstractJAXRSClient.getProxy(AbstractJAXRSClient.java:275)
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.annotation.SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.wireJAXRSClient(SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.java:464)
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.annotation.SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.wireSOAClient(SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.annotation.SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.access$000(SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.java:42)
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.annotation.SOAClientAnnotationProcessor$1.doWith(SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:605)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:585)
    at com.walmart.platform.soa.client.annotation.SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(SOAClientAnnotationProcessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 ... 20 more
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
 ... 31 more
```

FYI, I have added JaxB-Impl dependency explicitly because:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'example': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
```

What is the root cause for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `cxf-rt-rs-client` as dependency.

Moreover I would drop the jsr311 api and use the 2.0 one instead.

Comment: After adding cxf-rt-rs-client, build is success, but at run time facing NoSuchField error ::Reflection. Seems like the issue is with JaXB-impl version

Comment: Upgrading cxf 2.7.7 to 3.1.8. There is no issues with older version .But with 3.1.8 facing the below issue                                                             
 NO jaxb context can be created":com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.illegalannotationsexception:1 counts of illegalannotationexceptions. Transiet field cannot have any JAXB annotations. But it perflectly working with 2.7.7

Comment: I tried with 2.2.11 as well. Facing the same issue IllegalAnnotationException

Comment: The existing system is running good with 2.7.7 version with the following dependencies.
 cxf-api, cxf-core,cxf-rt-core,cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/jaxws/simple
cxf-rt-transports-http/local 
Jaxb-impl 2.5
javax-ws-rs-api 2.0-m10

Comment: In 3.1.8 all the above cxf jars are available with 3.1.8 except cxf-api and cxf-core. I have added cxf-rt-rs-client to support few class loader issues.
JAXB-IMPL is 2.2.11
javax-ws-rs-api 2.1-m09.

FYI, maven build is success for all the modules but while deploying the war file into the tomcat server facing JAXB IllegalAnnotationException 
I tried with JAXB-impl with the older version which is 2.5 , even tough getting the same exception.